# Upgrade kernel on debian

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, debian

When I try to compile kernel 3.14 on Debian 7.4 with the command make-kpkg:

```
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 178: make-kpkg: command not found
```

And I wondering can I install kernel without compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably haven't installed kernel-package, which contains `make-kpkg`. Better just forget about it, it's obsolete.

Just run `make deb-pkg` instead.

Comment: i have used even make deb-pkg clean